# Relating two different commits from two different repos

Tags: git, commit, gerrit, repo

I have 2 different repositories modified to solve 1 problem. I'd committed  the changes made in each repo and pushed to gerrit for review.

So I have 1 commit and 1 push for each repo.

How to relate or link both commits / pushs so other people will know that 1 problem was solved?

Answer (score 3):

In Gerrit changes can be grouped by **topics**. This is useful because it allows you to easily find related changes by using the ***topic:*** search operator. Also on the change screen changes with the same topic are displayed so that you can easily navigate between them.

See more info in Gerrit documentation:

- [Changes > Topics](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/concept-changes.html#topic)
- [User Guide > Using Topics](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#topics)

Answer (score 0):

If the repositories are completely unrelated (one not being the clone of the other), you will have no technical way to link them[*]

For semantic value, you could tag each commit with the same tag name in both repositories. And a tag name being clear enough on what the issue was while at the same time not being too long... which is often difficult (naming is always a difficult problem).

You have also the git `notes` feature, but this is kind of arcane, and not all tools, besides core git, know how to handle them (where tags are known everywhere). If using the `notes` feature you could put in each repository a note on the relevant commit ID being, as pure text, the commit ID or URL of the other commit.

Other than that, you can always have a `README` or `CHANGES` file in each repository listing things like that. It is however of course completely manual and non formatted.

[*] or if you want to be super-geeky you create a metarepository where you import both repositories in it (a git repository can have more than one root commit in fact, not always known, rarely useful, always complicated, but still possible); or you use `submodules`.